# Facebook Graph API - Events ticket_uri

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a ticket_uri to the event that I am creating.
I enabled the "Events Timezone" migration in my app settings.
I am posting on behalf of a user that is manager of the page.

Currently it's not working when I create a new event. The new event has no ticket uri.
If I update the new event, just after it's created, the ticket uri works...

**Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

```
    $fbEvent = $facebook->publish('/events', $event);

    if(isset($fbEvent['id']))
    {
        $facebook->publish('/' . $fbEvent['id'], array('ticket_uri' => 'http://lowiebenoot.be'));
    }
```

Updating right after it's created is just stupid...

Answer (score 1):

You must get a "Page access token" and then post to {page_id}/events. Here's a copy of the steps I've posted a couple of places:

1. Enable the "Events Timezone migration"
2. Log into FB as a user that has admin rights on the FB Page that we want events posted to
3. Use the APPLICATION's ID to build this link to authorize the
   managing of pages
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=MY_SITE_URL&scope=manage_pages,create_event&response_type=token
4. Exchange token for perm (longer token)
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APP_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=(token from step 3)
5. Visit this page, find the PAGE you want to post and copy the new
   access_token https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=
   (token from step 4)
6. Use this last token (from step 5) and the PAGE's ID to post to post
   the event per the instructions at
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#events

Note that if you create a lot of events, you will "spam" every user who Like'd the page. FB recently added the 'no_feed_story' option to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about the 'no_feed_story' option.